# Selecting Multiple Elements In A UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I found this code online and am surprised that it basically does the opposite of what I want it to do. Here are the methods...

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
        cell.tag = row;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSelection:)];
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
    }

    if ([selectedItems indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]] != NSNotFound) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Joe";

    return cell;
}

- (void)toggleSelection:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSUInteger index = [selectedItems indexOfObject:row];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        [selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else {
        [selectedItems addObject:row];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```

The result is a simple checkmark by each UIPickerView item. This is great and all, but by default all of the elements of the PickerView are selected, which means they display a checkmark (I want none of them to be selected, except the ones I choose specifically in my code). Can you possible edit my methods and try to figure out how to do what I'm doing.

Also how am I going to be able to see the elements the user selected in my code. Help!

Comment: If you have written this code very well can you give me sample code to implement.I have the same need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from this block, there's an array being stored called `selectedItems`, and it contains `NSNumber` objects corresponding to the rows.

```
if ([selectedItems indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]] != NSNotFound) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

If rowstarts checked, `selectedItems` must be initialised to contain an `NSNumber` object for every row.  Try initialising it to be empty instead.  To read what is selected, iterate through its content numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

Use UITableView and togggle the cell acessory type when select or deselect.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
```